# Xamarin forms Android Archive failed due to log4net.dll being used by another process

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022, archive

With a Xamarin.Forms solution that will build in release and deploy to a physical device I am having an issue archiving to get an APK file.

While trying to archive my Android project I am getting a failure due to log4net.dll being used by another process. This happens when I have deleted the bin and obj folders to force a recreation.

```
XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.OutputException: Failed to write 'C:\reposlocation\Xamarin.Android\obj\Release\130\android\assets\log4net.dll ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\reposlocation\Xamarin.Android\obj\Release\130\android\assets\log4net.dll' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters) in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/ModuleDefinition.cs:line 1160
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.WriteAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, String directory, WriterParameters writerParameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.WriteAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, String directory, WriterParameters writerParameters)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.OutputAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
Done building project "Xamarin.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

I am currently running VS Professional 2022 (4.8.09032), XamarinForms (5.0.2545), Log4net (2.0.15).

The application will archive if I set linking to none.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can confirm this is still happening in 5.0.0.2622 (XF) VS 2022 17.8.4, using .Net 4.8.09032